# Compare two IsoString date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, iso, toisostring

I want to compare two Iso string dates by days, date have this format :

**

> "2020-05-07T15:51:28.124Z"

**

I made this function to get the result of comparison by days :

```
  compareDatesByDays(higherDate, lowerDate) {
    const diffTime = Math.abs(higherDate - lowerDate)
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

    return diffDays
  }
```

Math.abs give NaN AND I think that does not work with string iso date!!

Comment: There are already many questions on [finding the difference between two dates in days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+two+dates+in+days). Note that your algorithm means that dates that differ by 1 ms will return 1 day difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  function compareDatesByDays(higherDate, lowerDate) {
    const d1 = new Date(higherDate);
    const d2 = new Date(lowerDate);
    const diffTime = Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return diffDays;
  }
  console.log(compareDatesByDays("2020-05-07T15:51:28.124Z", "2020-05-03T15:51:28.124Z")); // -> 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use a library rather than standard javascript dates.  The most popular is `moment.js`

In moment.js:

```js
moment(higherDate).diff(lowerDate, 'days') // returns int
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/